# masking multiband with rasterio

Tags: python, masking, rasterio

I have 2 multiband rasters and I want to mask some areas of one of them with values of the other one, so I write this code (I can't figure out why is not working):

```py
import os, rasterio
import numpy as np

feb = r'path\to\multiband\stack_1.img'
may = r'path\to\multiband\stack_2.img'
mask = r'path\to\mask_raster' #this one is just one band
outfile = r'path\to\outfile' #multiband

with rasterio.open(mask) as mascara:

    MASK = mascara.read() 

with rasterio.open(feb) as febrero:

    FEB = febrero.read([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) 


with rasterio.open(may) as mayo:

    MAY = mayo.read([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) 

for i in range(1,11):

    MAY = np.where(MASK == 1, FEB[i], MAY[i])

profile = mayo.meta
profile.update(dtype=rasterio.int16)

with rasterio.open(outfile, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(MAY.astype(rasterio.int16))
```

I get this error when running the code:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-054d59b9e8d1> in <module>()
     22 for i in range(1,11):
     23 
---> 24     MAY = np.where(MASK == 1, FEB[i], MAY[i])
     25 
     26 profile = mayo.meta

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I am able to do it one by one band, but then I have to do the stack again and overall I would like to know why the code doesn't works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that you need `MAY[i] = np.where(MASK == 1, FEB[i], MAY[i])` in your code. Note the indexing on the left hand side. Without this, `MAY[i]` will have the wrong shape on your second (`i=2`) loop iteration.

Rasterio tip: get the base profile for writing your output file from `profile = mayo.profile` instead of `meta`, it's more future-proof.

Comment: Yes, it was the MAY[i] in the left side. 1000 thanks, I hope I am gonna save a lot of time now!  Only one thing about the tip, when I change mayo.meta with mayo.profile it returns an error: "ValueError: can't read closed raster file", so I did it in the old fashion way!